# For loop after service retrieves data

Tags: javascript, angular

While trying to follow Angular's standards, I have split up my data retrieval and other view logic. I have created a service with multiple HTTP requests that fire when the component has initialized:

```
getData() {

    this.http.get(`https://example.com/corporate/Communications/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Corporate Announcements')/items?$orderBy=PublishDate desc&$filter=(PublishDate le '${moment().format()}' and ExpirationDate ge '${moment().format()}' and OData__ModerationStatus eq '0' and ReadyToPublish eq 'Yes' and BannerArticle eq 'Yes' and BannerExpiration ge '${moment().format()}')`).subscribe(data => {
      console.log("bannerItems", data['value']);
      this.bannerItems = data['value'];
    });

    this.http.get(`https://example.com/corporate/Communications/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Corporate Announcements')/items?$orderBy=PublishDate desc&$filter=(PublishDate le '${moment().format()}' and ExpirationDate ge '${moment().format()}' and OData__ModerationStatus eq '0' and ReadyToPublish eq 'Yes') and (BannerArticle eq 'No' or (BannerArticle eq 'Yes' and BannerExpiration le '${moment().format()}'))`).subscribe(data => {
      console.log("announcements", data['value']);
      this.announcements = data['value'];
    });

    this.http.get(`https://example.com/divisions/Risk/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Corporate Announcements')/items?$orderBy=ID desc&$filter=(Expires ge '${moment().format()}' and OData__ModerationStatus eq '0')`).subscribe(data => {
      console.log("riskAnnouncements", data['value']);
      this.riskAnnouncements = data['value'];
    });

    this.http.get(`https://example.com/divisions/it/servicestatus/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Service List')/items?$orderBy=Title asc&$filter=StatusKPI ne 'Service running normally'`).subscribe(data => {
      console.log("serviceAlerts", data['value']);
      this.serviceAlerts = data['value'];
    })

    this.http.get(`https://example.com/divisions/it/servicestatus/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Service Event History')/items?$orderBy=Title asc&$filter=(Modified ge '${moment().subtract(30, 'days').format()}' and Status eq 'Information Alert')`).subscribe(data => {
      console.log("serviceInfoAlerts", data['value']);
      this.serviceInfoAlerts = data['value'];
    })

}
```

In my component, I am trying to loop over the serviceAlerts array, however, the loop is firing before data is assigned to the array. How can I make the loop wait until all of `getData()` is finished before firing without using `setTimeout`?

Comment: you don't need to use setTimeout. Angular's http.get method returns an observable that you can subscribe to.  so your get data function should return the http.get request

Comment: if you are using rxjs use `subscribe`, or `forkJoin`
https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/forkJoin

Comment: so basically assuming you are using onInit to get the data, make sure you return it all as an observable (as mentioned above use forkJoin or flatMap) since you are using multiple get requests. Then set up an observable that you can equate to the return function and from then on you can subscribe to the data and do what you want with the loop.

Answer (score 1):

First of all the `getData()` in your service doesn't return anything.

If you are following angular coding standards, you will write diffrent methods for making these `http` calls (separation and clean code). ex:

```
getCodeData(){ return http.get("url").pipe(handleError())
getSecondCodeData(){ return http.get("Secondurl").pipe(handleError())
```

Now coming to your problem of getting data from all these methods:
You can use [RxJS ForkJoin](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/forkjoin.html) to achieve that effect:

```
Observable.forkJoin([
            this.myService.getCodeData(),
            this.myService.getSecondCodeData()
        ]).subscribe((results: any[]) => { 
        results[0] => will have the value from first http call and so on..
      })
```